# Taking an integer and creating a date format

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I can take a date and convert is to an integer.

```
date_as_integer = $("2020-06-13" | sed "s/-//g")
```

However is there a way to convert it back to date?

Comment: This is not bash syntax.

Comment: I will need to do a little math here. Like 20200515-1=20200514 And 20200514 to 2020-05-14

Will that work

Comment: `date +%F -d $((20200515-1))` prints out `2020-05-14`, so for simple addition of days, it would seem to work as you desire

Comment: @einfeyn496 Thank you. That resolves my issue

Comment: You might consider adding that use case to your question so that the answer provided by @glennjackman could be adapted to mention that it still covers such a use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing it with string manipulation using bash parameter expansion:

```bsh
date2int() {
  printf "%s\n" "${1//-/}"
}

int2date() {
  printf "%s-%s-%s\n" "${1:0:4}" "${1:4:2}" "${1:6:2}"
}

date +%F                                # => 2020-07-24
n=$(date2int "$(date +%F)"); echo "$n"  # => 20200724
d=$(int2date "$n"); echo "$d"           # => 2020-07-24
```

---

This technique is definitely **NOT** OK for date arithmetic.

```bsh
# subtract 2 days from Jan 1
date="2000-01-01"
n=$(date2int "$date")
int2date "$((n - 2))"          # => 2000-00-99
```

You might as well stick to GNU date

```bsh
date="2000-01-01"
date -d "$date - 2 day" "+%F"  # => 1999-12-30
```